I'm getting an error while printing qc.qasm()

I'm getting this error. Need help.

According to Qiskit 1.0 migration guide:

The QuantumCircuit.qasm method has been removed. Instead, use qasm2.dump or qasm2.dumps.

So, instead of
print(qc.qasm())

You should use
from qiskit.qasm2 import dumps
 
print(dumps(qc))


Thank you! It's working! <3
